# Adding Entire Solution To nuspec For Nuget Package Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm creating a nuget package as a solution for a template I'm having to create over and over again. I'm feeling like there is a better way to add an entire project as a nuget package then specifying all the files individually. Right now I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>SSOTemplateNonSAML</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>ssotemplate</title>
    <authors>Adam</authors>
    <owners>HQ</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>SSO's</description>
    <releaseNotes>Version 1.0</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>Template</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" target="content"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

But what I want is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>SSOTemplateNonSAML</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>ssotemplate</title>
    <authors>Adam</authors>
    <owners>HQ</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>SSO's</description>
    <releaseNotes>Version 1.0</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>Template</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file Take all the files in the solution />
  </files>
</package>
```

How can I do this without specifying each class? and if I can't do this can I at least specify the class library? Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you want to create a nuget package for an solution with many files or want to create a VS project template with nuget package installed? We need to know what do you do.

Comment: nuget package for solution with many files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) which allow you selecting multi files to be included in the package.

Answer (score 1):

After building class library project, it will generate a dll which contains all class file content in your project. We could pack this assembly directly with following command.

> nuget spec MyAssembly.dll

If there has any other files that not build as content in assembly, you could assign the files folder in `<file>` node as below:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\..\SomeRoot\**\*.*" target="" />
</files>
```

Please refer to:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

And if there has several projects in one solution, we could add the class library assembly with following format in .nuspec file.

```
 <file src="A\bin\Release\A.dll" target="lib" />
 <file src="B\bin\Release\B.dll" target="lib" />
```

Comment: Yes this works for sure, though I'm trying to avoid adding all the files manually like this